# how to set a menubar icon on mac osx using wx

Tags: macos, wxpython, wxwidgets

I could not find any pointers on how to create a menubar icon on OSX using wx. I originally thought that the wxTaskBarIcon class would do, but it actually creates an icon on the Dock. On Windows, wxTaskBarIcon creates a Systray icon and associated menu, and I would think that on mac osx it would create a menubar icon, I guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `wxTaskBarIconType` to `STATUSITEM`, not `DOCK`. The Cocoa APIs for this are `NSStatusBar` and `NSStatusItem`; [here's the code in wxWidgets that calls to them](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/attachment/ticket/6860/taskbar.diff).

Comment: Hmm, I don' get it. That's C code. How do you set the taskbaricontype to STATUSITEM in Python?

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-mac/browse_thread/thread/6e50401523c38903?pli=1) by Robin Dunn, the creator of wxPython, explains that wxPython doesn't support menubar icons on mac yet. They only support the Dock.

Comment: Robin Dunn's post is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 1):

As of wxPython 2.9.2.0 `wx.TaskBarIcon` will create a menubar icon now instead on OSX, so long as you call `SetIcon`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example on wiki.wxpython.org that puts an icon in the "status menus" section (right-hand side) of the macOS menu bar (ignore the page title):
https://wiki.wxpython.org/Custom%20Mac%20OsX%20Dock%20Bar%20Icon

It works for me with macOS High Sierra (10.13.3) running python 2.7.14 (installed using miniconda) with wxpython 3.0.0.0 osx-cocoa (classic).

Similarly, it works with python 3.6.4 and wxpython 4.0.1 osx-cocoa (phoenix);
minor code changes required:

- you must import wx.adv
- wx.TaskBarIcon becomes wx.adv.TaskBarIcon
- wx.IconFromBitmap   becomes wx.Icon

This generates a status/notification/taskbar-type icon on other platforms as well.