# How to add OSX menu bar icon with wxPython

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, taskbar, menubar

I would like to add an icon to the OSX menu bar at the top of the screen using wxPython. I have tried  wx.TaskBarIcon, which adds a System Tray icon in Windows, but this doesn't work - it changes the Dock icon for the app instead. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace the Apple icon on the top, left corner of the screen with another icon?  I haven't seen any OSX programs that do this so I don't think wxPython will be able to either.

Comment: No, I want to add a new icon towards the top-right of the screen, near to where the clock, battery and wi-fi status icons appear. This must be possible since I have many other apps that do it (dropbox, gmail notifier etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set a menubar icon on mac osx using wx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145894/how-to-set-a-menubar-icon-on-mac-osx-using-wx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that with wxPython2.9-osx-cocoa-py2.7 you can in fact put up a menubar icon. It looks like you can also call `PopupMenu()` on `TaskBarIcon` to attach a menu, which you should be able to use to create a full blown OSX menu bar application.

```
import wx

class TaskBarFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR |
                                              wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)

        self.tbicon = wx.TaskBarIcon()
        icon = wx.Icon('myicon.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.tbicon.SetIcon(icon, '')


app = wx.App(False)
frame = TaskBarFrame(None)
frame.Show(False)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided here on [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-mac/browse_thread/thread/6e50401523c38903) - in summary, **you can't do it**.

Answer (score 2):

It seems now you can:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/Custom%20Mac%20OsX%20Dock%20Bar%20Icon?highlight=%28wx%5C.TaskBarIcon%29

just copy and paste the code and run it ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/env pythonw

import wx
import wx.lib.embeddedimage

WXPdemo = wx.lib.embeddedimage.PyEmbeddedImage(
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAWlJ"
    "REFUWIW1V1sSwjAIBMebeBU9db2KZ8EPmxbCI4TUnXGskWaXDQktwhjErjERP4XRhER08iPi"
    "5SKiyQR5JyI7xxB3j7wn5GI6V2hFxM0gJtjYANFBiIjQu7L/1lYlwR0QxLDZhE0II1+CtwRC"
    "RI8riBva7DL7CC9VAwDbbxwKtdDXwBi7K+1zCP99T1vDFedd8FBwYd6BCAUXuACEF7QsbET/"
    "FaHs+gDQw4vOLNHkMojAnTw8nlNipIiwmR0DCXJbjCXkFCAL23BnpQgRWt1EMbyujCK9AZzZ"
    "f+b3sX0oSqJQ6EorFeT4NiL6Wtj0+LXnQAzThYoAAsN6ehqR3sHExmcEqGeFApQLcTvm5Kt9"
    "wkHGgb+RZwSkyc1dwOcpCtCoNKSz6FRCUQ3o7Nn+5Y+Lg+y5CIXlcyAk99ziiQS32+svz/UY"
    "vClJoLpIC8gi+VwwfDecEiEtT/WZTJDf94uk1Ru8vbz0cvoF7S2DnpeVL9UAAAAASUVORK5C"
    "YII=")

class DemoTaskBarIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):
    TBMENU_RESTORE = wx.NewId()
    TBMENU_CLOSE   = wx.NewId()
    TBMENU_CHANGE  = wx.NewId()
    TBMENU_REMOVE  = wx.NewId()

    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.TaskBarIcon.__init__(self)
        self.frame = frame

        # Set the image
        icon = self.MakeIcon(WXPdemo.GetImage())
        self.SetIcon(icon, "wxPython Demo")
        self.imgidx = 1

        # bind some events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnTaskBarActivate)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnTaskBarActivate, id=self.TBMENU_RESTORE)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnTaskBarClose, id=self.TBMENU_CLOSE)


    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        """
        This method is called by the base class when it needs to popup
        the menu for the default EVT_RIGHT_DOWN event.  Just create
        the menu how you want it and return it from this function,
        the base class takes care of the rest.
        """
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(self.TBMENU_RESTORE, "Restore wxPython Demo")
        menu.Append(self.TBMENU_CLOSE,   "Close wxPython Demo")
        return menu


    def MakeIcon(self, img):
        """
        The various platforms have different requirements for the
        icon size...
        """
        if "wxMSW" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            img = img.Scale(16, 16)
        elif "wxGTK" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            img = img.Scale(22, 22)
        # wxMac can be any size upto 128x128, so leave the source img alone....
        icon = wx.IconFromBitmap(img.ConvertToBitmap() )
        return icon


    def OnTaskBarActivate(self, evt):
        if self.frame.IsIconized():
            self.frame.Iconize(False)
        if not self.frame.IsShown():
            self.frame.Show(True)
        self.frame.Raise()


    def OnTaskBarClose(self, evt):
        wx.CallAfter(self.frame.Close)



class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Hello World")
        self.tbicon = DemoTaskBarIcon(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)

    def OnCloseWindow(self, evt):
        self.tbicon.Destroy()
        evt.Skip()


app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```