# NSStatusItem in Python

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, wxpython, tkinter

Is there any way to create a menubar app in python (The obj-c equivalent appears to be NSStatusItem) using either wxPython or Tkinter? Ideally, I'd like to keep my program in pure python, so I would like to not use PyObjC.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/145894/67988.

Answer (score 3):

According to Robin Dunn (creator of wxPython), wxPython 2.9.2 supports NSStatusItem (and related widgets): http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Raising-a-wxpython-frame-from-a-PyObjC-NSStatusBar-td4559330.html

It also supports the Taskbar / system tray icons on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this: [How to make an menu bar (system tray) app for OSX in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544853/how-to-make-an-menu-bar-system-tray-app-for-osx-in-python/8546218#8546218)

In the answer to the question, Jared creates an app with [rumps](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps).

You can also check [this code](https://gist.github.com/yeonsh/9b084059c4eb48a730a9) to create a menubar app using PyObjC only.