# How to make a status bar icon with wxWidgets on Mac in C++?

Tags: macos, c++11, clang, wxwidgets

I want to create a status bar icon with my C++ application using wxWidgets. Is this possible? I didn't find anything useful regarding this problem. I do not talk about a menu bar but a status bar (icon). Like for example the dropbox app has. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/macos-status-bar-apps/) using Xcode that describes what I want to do but my application uses wxWidgets with C++. I did not include code here because I just need an example how to do it. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306788/3871673) is a post to some python code that looks like it can do this, but I did not find these header files.

Here an example image of what I want to archive:
[image]

Comment: Isn't `wxTaskBarIcon` with `wxTBI_CUSTOM_STATUSITEM` type what what you were looking for?

Comment: @catalin Oh that looks promising! I will try to find a sample code in C++.

Comment: @catalin I did't get i working in C++, I found an example code in python but don't know the equivalent in C++, can you help me?

Comment: In `taskbar` sample that comes with wxW, file `tbtest.cpp`, search for `m_dockIcon = new MyTaskBarIcon(wxTBI_DOCK)` and replace the `iconType` value with the one mentioned earlier. You can also build and run the sample and see how it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid I didn't found that myself.. but strange that my web search didn't come up with that. The taskbar sample did exactly what I need, thus creating a status icon with context menu! I will study it's code.